# Use graph and iteration equation solver to solve an iteritive map and interpret the resutls

Tags: mathematical-modeling, fixed-point-iteration

Following is a nonlinear map:

$$x_{t+1} = \dfrac{x^4_t}{x^4_t+0.05}$$

$(a)$ Use graph plotter do determine the fixed points $x^*_1$, $x^*_2$, $x^*_3$, $x^*_4$...... Approximate the value of these fixed points to one decimal place and determine the stability of each fixed point.

I used this online graphing website to graph the two functions. 
One is $y_1=x$, the second function is $y_2=\dfrac{x^4}{x^4+0.05}$. Based on the results, I saw there fixed point, at $(0,0)$, $(0.4495,0.4495)$, and$ (0.9398,0.9398)$

[image]

But if I rearranage $$x = \dfrac{x^4}{x^4+0.05}$$ into $$x^5 - x^4 + 0.05x = 0$$ and use a quartic equation solver to solve for the roots. These are the results I got are $x=0$, $x=  0.9398$, $x=  0.4495$, and $x= -0.1946 \pm   0.2837i$

What does the complex roots mean here?

Then I used the wolfram online iteration equation solver to solve for 
$$x_{t+1} = \dfrac{x^4_t}{x^4_t+0.05}$$

Used $x(0) = 0.4495$ as the initial condition, which is the fixed point I estimated earlier using the graph.

Following is the results I got. How do I interpret it? Why it didn't give me the fixed point $x= 0.9398$ that I got with the graphing calculator? 
[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: I have no idea, which type of interpretation you mean, but $x\approx 0,9398$ will you get, if you start with $x_0:=1$. The starting values have to be near by the fixed points.

Comment: Are the two complex roots also fixed point? Can they be solved using graphical methods?

Comment: I have never done this but I am sure that this is possible, using two variables instead of one for $x$: $x:=x_1+i\cdot x_2$. Then one has $x_3=(x_1+i\cdot x_2)^5-(x_1+i\cdot x_2)^4+0.05(x_1+i\cdot x_2)$, a graphic of three dimensions.